# How can I install Windows XP on a computer with only USB 3 sockets?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, windows-installation, usb-3

I have an Intel NUC computer. It only supports USB 3 and has no PS2 port. It does have a network socket if that helps. If I try to install Windows XP (or any version before Windows 10) the keyboard and mouse stop working on the installation screen because the installer doesn't support USB 3.

Intel make a custom Windows 7 installer with USB 3 support but not for any other OS.

**How can I install Windows XP on the NUC when I can't use a keyboard or mouse during the installation because the sockets are USB 3 but the installer doesn't support USB 3?**

Comment: Perhaps there is an option to "downgrade" the ports in the BIOS? Is there any drivers for the chipset for any other windows version than Windows 10?

Comment: You can’t.  Windows XP doesn’t support being installed from a USB 3 device.  Windows 7 does if you add the driver.  However newer Intel processors also are a problem because they also block the installation process due to USB 3.  What you want is literally not possible

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have all the hardware drivers that Windows XP would need on the NUC?

So far as I can tell, [Intel don't support XP](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/70407/Intel-NUC-Kits). This is hardly surprising.

### HDD transplant

You might be able to get somewhere by removing the NUC's hard disk, putting it into a PC that has USB2 or PS2 connectors, installing XP there then replacing the HD in the NUC and see if XP can boot in safe mode. If so you can then install the drivers needed for the NUC hardware. Assuming you have some drivers.

### PCIe

Some [NUCs](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/boards/nuc5i5mybe.html) have a PCIe slot. PCIe PS/2 cards exist. Whether XP would recognise them is pot-luck I guess.

### VM

I'd prefer to try to install XP as a VM under Windows-10 (or some other supported OS or Hypervisor).

---

Footnote:

I guess you are aware that it isn't safe to install Windows XP on a computer with any kind of network interface that might become connected, even indirectly, to the Internet.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the OS BSODs even if you successfully installed.  Windows XP is VERY old.  I had to upgrade when I tried to use it on a re-built Core 2 Duo system.  I never bothered to figure out what caused it.  I can't imagine it getting better with even newer hardware.